# What key for Ubuntu option during pre boot (small twist)?

Tags: boot, grub2

This question is close to others on the site but I still haven't found an answer.  I have a Toshiba Satellite with Windows 7.  Ubuntu has been installed on it and I have used it before.  I haven't used this computer in a while and now I've forgotten the key prompt to have the option to boot to Ubuntu.  The default is Windows.

I also have pre boot true crypt authentication on this machine.  The thing I've tried is pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>.  This brings up the grub but doesn't list Ubuntu as an option.

I think the solution is a combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd> and another F key but I've had zero success over the last few days.

Answer (score 2):

Here what they say in this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2?action=show&redirect=GRUB2#Editing%20Menus%20During%20Boot)

> The user may be able to display the menu in one or more of the following ways:
>
> 1. Holding down the SHIFT key early in the boot process until the menu displays. GRUB 2 searches for a depressed SHIFT key signal during boot. If the key is pressed or GRUB 2 cannot determine the status of the key, the menu is displayed.
> 2. Pressing the ESC key during a 3 second window as GRUB 2 runs.